# Is there a way to differentiate music and talking from a video?

Tags: audio

Let say I have a video with a Vtuber singing songs and talking between songs, for example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjYSd1ykmFw

I would like to mark the starting time and ending time of each song, but it is a bit time consuming to mark it manually, and it seems there is no existing tools for this. I am considering writing my own tools, but I have no experience in handling sound with program. How should I approach this problem, at a high-level?

Answer (score 2):

Slice the audio into segments.
Use a BPM measurement tool to find beats per minute in each segment.
Adjacent segments with similar BPM are likely from the same song.
For a spoken word segment, we’d expect that no consistent beat can be recognized.